# Svelte srcObject property on video element

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, mediastream

I am currently trying to attach a video stream (MediaStream) to a video HTML element in a Svelte Compontnt.

Now I had to find out that according to the docs, there is no possibility to "bind" a srcObject to a media element.

Here are the docs for reference:
https://svelte.dev/tutorial/media-elements

Now, while searching for a solution, I came across the following issue of the Svelte project. It describes exactly the same problem that I have. It also points out that Svelte does not yet offer an in-house solution to implement this project.

The only proposed solution is as follows:

```
<script>
  export let stream;

   function srcObject(node, stream) {
    node.srcObject = stream;
    return {
      update(newStream) {
        if (node.srcObject != newStream) {
          node.srcObject = newStream
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<video use:srcObject={stream} autoplay playsinline></video>
```

Link to the Issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3492

**Question:**

Is this currently still the only way to attach a MediaStream in svelte to a Media HTML element?

Since the post is from 2020 and there is no further movement in the issue, I hope that other solutions will be recommended in the meantime.